# Mongodb database design

Tags: database-design, mongodb, schema, nosql, application-design

I'm planning to implement this schema in Mongodb, I have been doing some readings about schema design, and the notion was whenever you structure your data like a relational database you must be doing something wrong.

[image]

My questions:

- what should I do when collection size gets larger than 16MB limit?
  app_log in server_log collections gets might in some cases grow larger than 16MB depending how busy the server is.

  I'm aware of the cap feature that I could use, but the requirement is store all logs for 90 days.
- Do you see any potential issues with my design?
- Is it a good practice to have the application check for collection size and create new collection by day / hour ..etc to accommodate log size growth?

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at mongodb's recommendations when using mongodb for logging https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-log-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16 MB is the maximum size of single document, e.g. one user.

The size of the collection is limit by maximum database only.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

So logging to the database should be no problem. In my opinion using sensible indizes including _id is superior to a heap of collections.

It is not clear to me what you actually want to store in your database so I cannot really comment on the structure. Generally speaking there are three ways to handle relations: Using arrays

- storing subdocuments or
- ids of documents (You would have to retrieve those via a separate database request)
- invert the relation by giving all referenced documents a field containing the parent document id

If you give more details, chances are somebody can give you a more detailed answer.